# How to perform Control + Save operation with Selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Am trying to save .html page into my desktop using selenium .

Can anyone pls help?

Comment: do u mean ctrl+S operation using selenium webdriver

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this? What are you trying to achieve? Are you sure Selenium is the right tool for your job?

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [Advanced User Interactions API](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#advanceduserinteractions):

```
new Actions(driver)
    .sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "s"))
    .perform();
```

This will open the Save As dialog in which you then need to navigate manually / using the Java's [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) class:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// press Ctrl+S the Robot's way
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_S);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_S);
// press Enter
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Presses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Beware that will *not* work on every system and/or browser.

Answer (score -1):

```java
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;                              
String base64string = (String) js.executeScript("var c = document.createElement('canvas');"
    + " var ctx = c.getContext('2d');"
    + "var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];"
    + "c.height=img.naturalHeight;"
    + "c.width=img.naturalWidth;"
    + "ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,img.naturalWidth, img.naturalHeight);"
    + "var base64String = c.toDataURL();"
    + "return base64String;");
String[] base64Array = base64string.split(",");

String base64 = base64Array[base64Array.length - 1];

byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64);

ByteArrayInputStream memstream = new ByteArrayInputStream(data);

BufferedImage saveImage = ImageIO.read(memstream);

ImageIO.write(saveImage, "png", new File("path"));
```

Comment: Not sure if submitting an answer to a 6 years old question with accepted answers will help

Comment: Please read the rules on answering questions as well. If you can provide some good advice to the question for future users, and you think your answer can be useful, please add an explanation and format your answer as per the guidelines.  Please read the help section.